# Unexpected dropping of end of string with gsub()

Tags: r, gsub

I'm confused by the following behavior.

```
> tmpString <- Sys.time()
> tmpString
[1] "2021-06-17 11:50:52 EDT"
> gsub(" ",  "_", tmpString)
[1] "2021-06-17_11:50:52"
> gsub(" ",  "_", tmpString, fixed=TRUE)
[1] "2021-06-17_11:50:52"
```

Why is the " EDT" at the end of tmpString being lost?

For completeness,

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock        
>
```

Comment: The timezone is added within the print method.  It isn't actually stored in your data.

Comment: as @Dason said the timezone is part of the object class. Sys.time() is a POSIXct / POSIXt but when you use gsub the object gets converted to character and looses additional info. You shoudl check out the format() function if you want to keep the object class... you can always check the class of an object/variable by using the class() call on it

Comment: Ahhh.. I see. Thanks.

Comment: one option for the format call would be this: format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S %Z") ... one way to show the abreviation is to inform it directly in the format call but that might not suit your case: format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S %Z", tz = "GMT") ... if it does not solve your problem, I am afraid you have to read into the topic about the timezone abreviation and might possibly use the lubridate package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmpString` is not a string.  As mentioned in the comments it is a POSIXct object which internally is the number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch and it is the `print` function which shows it with a time zone.  Better to call it `tmp` instead of `tmpString` and then explicitly use `format` to convert it to a string.  (Below we used `sub` to replace the first space but use `gsub` as in the question if you want both spaces replaced.)

```
tmp <- Sys.time()
sub(" ", "_", format(tmp, usetz = TRUE))
## [1] "2021-06-17_12:39:51 EDT"
```

Also note the existence of `format_ISO8601` which you might prefer:

```
format_ISO8601(tmp, usetz = TRUE)
## [1] "2021-06-17T12:39:51-0400"
```